# How to use downloadable assets in electron react boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron, electron-react-boilerplate

I developed app based on `electron-react-boilerplate` and now I want to lower package size by moving my video/audio assets to CDN to be downloaded on first run. Assets are downloaded to `assets/` directory and this directory is added to `extraResources`.  Now when I'm using import or require in react - it cant be compilled because in dev such files doesn't exists. How I should now import such downloadable assets in react?